# Xamarin Forms Library adds extra permissions even though I remove them

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-manifest

I'm about to publish an Android app but Xamarin automatically adds the following permissions to my apk file:
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

How can I remove ?

Thanks

Comment: Has worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

It's coming from `AssemblyInfo.cs`, you can remove it from there.
To remove further permissions added automatically by third-party libraries you can specify:

```
tools:node="remove"
```

at the permission "incriminated"